# Не срабатывает вызов окна при нажатии кнопки

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, popup

Всем привет.

Установлена кнопка "Купить в 1 клик", такая же стоит в карточке товара.
Проблема в том, что тут (в категориях) она не работает, а в карточке она работает.

Установил кнопку этим кодом:

```html
<div id="enquiry">
    <input type="button" name="contact" value="<?php echo empty($form_data['custom_label']) ?
            __('Make an enquiry for this product', 'product-enquiry-for-woocommerce'): $form_data['custom_label'];?>" class="contact wpi-button loop_add_to_cart_button button alt" />
</div>
```

Выдернув из общего файла:

```html
<?php

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'wdm_pe_init');
function wdm_pe_init()
{
    load_plugin_textdomain('product-enquiry-for-woocommerce', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/languages/');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'check_woo_dependency');

//Check whether WooCommerce is active or not

function check_woo_dependency()
{
    if (!is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')) {
        echo "<div class='error'><p>". sprintf(__('%s WooCommerce %s plugin is not active. In order to make %s Product Enquiry %s plugin work, you need to install and activate %s WooCommerce %s first', 'product-enquiry-for-woocommerce'), "<strong>", "</strong>", "<strong>", "</strong>", "<strong>", "</strong>") . "</p></div>";

        if (is_plugin_active('product-enquiry-for-woocommerce/product-enquiry-for-woocommerce.php')) {
                deactivate_plugins(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
        }
        unset($_GET['activate']);
    }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'messageProductEnquiryPro');

function messageProductEnquiryPro()
{
    if (is_plugin_active('product-enquiry-pro/product_enquiry_pro.php')) {
        echo "<div class='error'><p>". __('Product Enquiry Pro plugin is active. Please deactivate in order to install Product Enquiry Free') ."</p></div>";
    }
}

/*function deactivate_dependent_product_enquiry_pro()
{
    $my_plugin = 'product-enquiry-pro/product_enquiry_pro.php';

    deactivate_plugins($my_plugin);
}
*/
add_action('wp_head', 'wdm_display_btn_func', 11);

function wdm_display_btn_func()
{

    $form_init_data = get_option('wdm_form_data');

    // if (!empty($form_init_data)) {
    if (isset($form_init_data['show_after_summary'])) {
        if ($form_init_data['show_after_summary'] == 'after_add_cart') {
            //show ask button after a single product summary add to cart
            add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'ask_about_product_button', 30);
        } elseif ($form_init_data['show_after_summary'] == 'after_product_summary') {
                add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'ask_about_product_button');
        }
    } else {
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'ask_about_product_button', 30);
    }

    
        // if (isset($form_init_data['show_after_summary'])) {
            // if () {
                //show ask button after a single product summary
            // }
        // }
    // } else {
        //show ask button after a single product summary as default
    // }
}

function ask_about_product_button()
{
    $form_data = get_option('wdm_form_data');
    global $isProduct;
    $isProduct = true;
    ?>
     <div id="enquiry" style="position: relative;display: inline-block;margin-top: 80px;">
            <input type="button" name="contact" value="<?php echo empty($form_data['custom_label']) ?
            __('Make an enquiry for this product', 'product-enquiry-for-woocommerce'): $form_data['custom_label'];?>" class="contact wpi-button single_add_to_cart_button button alt" />
     </div>
        
<?php }

add_action('wp_footer', 'ask_about_product');

function ask_about_product()
{
    $form_data = get_option('wdm_form_data');
    global $wpdb,$post, $isProduct;
    $query = "select user_email from {$wpdb->posts} as p join {$wpdb->users} as u on p.post_author=u.ID where p.ID=%d";
    $authorEmail = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query, $post->ID));

    ?>
     <!-- Page styles -->
        <?php
           // wp_enqueue_style("wdm-contact-css", plugins_url("css/contact.css", __FILE__));
        if (is_product()) {
            wp_enqueue_style("wdm-juery-css", plugins_url("css/wdm-jquery-ui.css", __FILE__));
            if (isset($form_data[ 'user_custom_css' ])) {
                wp_add_inline_style('wdm-juery-css', $form_data[ 'user_custom_css' ]);
            }
        }
        ?>
    <?php if ($isProduct/*&&(!empty($form_data['show_at_page_end']))||(!empty($form_data['show_after_summary']))*/) { ?>
    <div id="contact-form" title="<?php _e("Купить в 1 клик", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?>" style="display:none;">
    <form id="enquiry-form" action="#" method="POST">
    <label id="wdm_product_name" for='product_name'> <?php echo get_the_title();?> </label>
        <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
        <input type="hidden" name="wdm_product_id" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" />
        <label for='contact-name'><?php _e("Ваше Имя", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?>:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='wdm_customer_name' value=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">  
        <label for='contact-tel'><?php _e("Телефон", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?>:</label>                    
        <input type="tel" id="contact-tel" class="contact-input" name="wdm_customer_tel" placeholder="89998887766" pattern="8[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}"  required />
        </div>
        <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">  
        <label for='contact-kolvo'><?php _e("Количество", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?>:</label>         
        <input type="tel" id="contact-kolvo" class="contact-input" name="wdm_customer_kolvo"  placeholder="01" pattern="[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}"  required />
        </div>
    <!--     <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
        <label for='contact-email'>*<?php _e("Ваш Email", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?>:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='wdm_customer_email'  />
        </div> 
        <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
        <label for='contact-subject'>*<?php _e("Телефон", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?>:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-subject' class='contact-input' name='wdm_subject' value=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
        <label for='contact-subject'>*<?php _e("Количество", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?>:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-subject' class='contact-input' name='wdm_subject' value=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
        <label for='contact-message'>*<?php _e("Количество", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?>:</label>
        <input id='contact-message' class='contact-input' role="dialog" name='wdm_enquiry' />
        </div> -->
        <?php if (!empty($form_data['enable_send_mail_copy'])) {?>
        <div class="wdm-pef-send-copy">
        <input type='checkbox' id='contact-cc' name='cc' value='1' /> <span class='contact-cc'>
        <?php _e("Send me a copy", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?></span>
        </div>
        <?php }?>
        <div id="errors"></div>
        <div class="wdm-enquiry-action-btns">
        <button id="send-btn" type='submit' class='contact-send contact-button' ><?php _e("Отправить", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?></button>
    <!--    <button id="cancel" type='button' class='contact-cancel contact-button' ><?php _e("Cancel", "product-enquiry-for-woocommerce");?></button>   -->
        </div>
        <?php echo wp_nonce_field('enquiry_action', 'product_enquiry', true, false); ?>
        
  </form>
------------------------ это конечно не весь код ---------------------------
```

Comment: есть ли что нибудь в консоле?

Comment: в консоли тишина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что при клике срабатывает обработчик в файле /wp-content/plugins/product-enquiry-for-woocommerce/js/contact.js, строка 15. Он пытается запустить функцию dialog, а та ищет `$( "#contact-form" )`.

У вас в карточке товара такой `<div id="contact-form"...` присутствует, а на странице категории - нет. Это заготовка под форму, которая спрятана до клика.

Скопируйте этот div с содержимым из карточки контакта, и все будет работать.

У вас в html - коде категории должно быть такое:

```
<div id="contact-form" style="width: auto; min-height: 42px; max-height: none; height: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
<form id="enquiry-form" action="#" method="POST" _lpchecked="1">
<label id="wdm_product_name" for="product_name"> Агростретч POLIFILM 500мм 25мкм 1800 метров Германия, цвет белый </label>
    <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
    <input type="hidden" name="wdm_product_id" value="948">
    <label for="contact-name">Ваше Имя:</label>
    <input type="text" id="contact-name" class="contact-input" name="wdm_customer_name" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">  
    <label for="contact-tel">Телефон:</label>                    
    <input type="tel" id="contact-tel" class="contact-input" name="wdm_customer_tel" placeholder="89998887766" pattern="8[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">  
    <label for="contact-kolvo">Количество:</label>         
    <input type="tel" id="contact-kolvo" class="contact-input" name="wdm_customer_kolvo" placeholder="01" pattern="[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}" required="">
    </div>
<!--     <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
    <label for='contact-email'>*Ваш Email:</label>
    <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='wdm_customer_email'  />
    </div> 
    <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
    <label for='contact-subject'>*Телефон:</label>
    <input type='text' id='contact-subject' class='contact-input' name='wdm_subject' value=""  />
    </div>
    <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
    <label for='contact-subject'>*Количество:</label>
    <input type='text' id='contact-subject' class='contact-input' name='wdm_subject' value=""  />
    </div>
    <div class="wdm-pef-form-row">
    <label for='contact-message'>*Количество:</label>
    <input id='contact-message' class='contact-input' role="dialog" name='wdm_enquiry' />
    </div> -->
            <div id="errors"></div>
    <div class="wdm-enquiry-action-btns">
    <button id="send-btn" type="submit" class="contact-send contact-button">Отправить</button>
<!--    <button id="cancel" type='button' class='contact-cancel contact-button' >Cancel</button>   -->
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="product_enquiry" name="product_enquiry" value="374ba4ce4d"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/product/agrostretch-polifilm-500mm-25mkm-1800-metrov-germaniya-tsvet-belyj/">        
</form>
<div class="contact-bottom"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Brought to you by WisdmLabs: </a><a href="https://wisdmlabs.com/woocommerce-extension-development-customization-services/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Expert WooCommerce Developer</a><a href="#" onclick="return false;"></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: всяко разно пробывал, не работает((

Comment: Неправильно пробуете

Comment: в файле contact.js вот это:

Comment: jQuery(function($) {
     dialog = $( "#contact-form" ).dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       height: 'auto',
       width: '20em',
       modal: true,
       fluid: true,
       resizable: false,
     //draggable: false,
   //opacity:0.75,
   show: function() {$(this).fadeIn(500);},
   hide:function() {$(this).fadeOut(500);},
 });
     $( "#enquiry input.contact" ).click(function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
 //  $("#contact-form").closest(".ui-dialog").css("position","fixed");
});

Comment: Что вы мне это показываете, я это давно увидел, и на основании этого написал свой ответ.

Comment: Дополнил ответ примером html-кода, который должен быть на странице категории

Comment: почему то всё криво косо, хотя html вроде такой же

Comment: как будто стили не подгружаются и форма скрыта до нажатия только на первом товаре, а на последующих раскрыта

Comment: Какие стили?? У вас нет html-кода на странице!

Comment: Как это нет если кнопки работают и отправляется форма, только товар показывает всегда один и тот же

Comment: Вы в вопросе что писали? Не работает кнопка на странице категории. Я вам объяснил, почему

Comment: Верно, за это спасибо)